# Is it possible to copy data of C* one table to another from spark without loading data into spark memory?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-streaming, datastax-enterprise

Me using spark-sql-2.4.1v , kafka with Cassandra. I have a scenario where I would get different transnational data which might consists update records... 
For update records I will get a flag with "U" , for which the existing records in the "table" of cassandra should be copied to "table_hist".

Here I have "table" and "table_hist" are of same fields , just name differ.

In order words, I need to execute queries at cassandra cluster rather than pulling data into spark layer.

**Ex queries :**

```
UPDATE table SET end_date = '2019-08-31'  where companyid=1   if exists;

INSERT into table_hist(companyid,companyname,country,start_date,end_date)
VALUES (1,'Apple Inc','CAN','2019-08-31','9999-09-09') IF NOT EXISTS;
```

Is this possible without copying the data into spark memory.

Thanks.

Comment: `Is this possible without copying the data into spark memory.`

Data must go through memory...is the question how to load without loading `the entire dataset` in memory at once?

Comment: If that's the question, the answer is yes but you don't have to do anything special. Spark will write as it reads.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the previous answers, Cassandra doesn't distinguish between UPDATE and INSERT - for your use case, you just need to get your data into the DataFrame and write into Cassandra. It will update existing records, or insert new data. You may need to use the [ignoreNulls configuration property](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#globally-treating-all-nulls-as-unset) to not to write `null` instead of real data.